# Listen to a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible that I can listen to a event where a child element is beind added to a parent dom element .I want to invoke a routine whenever a child elements gets added to dom element dynamically .

Comment: Please update the question with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(element).bind("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
  ...
});
```